# Multiple select filters with ajax post

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have 4 select lists with following ID's: price_sort, power_sort, area_sort, source_sort. And i'm using jQuery `.change()` function, to send POST data with ajax to get response from controller with sorted results.

Javascript:

```
        $('#price_sort').change(function () {
            var price_sort = $(this).val();

            // sessionStorage.setItem('product', $(this).val());

            $.ajax({
                method: 'post',
                headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
                url: '/products/filters',
                data: {
                    order: price_sort
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#products').html(data.products_view);
                    // console.log(data);
                },
                error: function(jqxhr, status, exception) {
                    console.log('Error ' + exception);
                }
            });
        });
```

Currently i made it working with just 1 select, but how do i track with `.change()` all 4 select lists and send data?

Comment: may be using if..else with || operator you can so it.

Comment: Why the hell it's marked as duplicate, Rory? Your link to a question is different than mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you send all 4 values over ajax like this:

```
$('#price_sort,#power_sort,#area_sort,#source_sort').change(function () {
            var price_sort = $('#price_sort').val();
            var power_sort= $('#power_sort').val();
            var area_sort= $('#area_sort').val();
            var source_sort= $('#source_sort').val();

            // sessionStorage.setItem('product', $(this).val());

            $.ajax({
                method: 'post',
                headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
                url: '/products/filters',
                data: {
                    price_sort: price_sort,
                    power_sort: power_sort,
                    area_sort: area_sort,
                    source_sort: source_sort
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#products').html(data.products_view);
                    // console.log(data);
                },
                error: function(jqxhr, status, exception) {
                    console.log('Error ' + exception);
                }
            });
        });
```

if you want to sort by a single type then i suggest you get the id and pass it as a type of sort

```
$('#price_sort,#power_sort,#area_sort,#source_sort').change(function () {
var sortType = this.id;
var order = $(this).val();
...
 data: {
  order:order,
  sortType:sortType 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an ID as you do in `$('#price_sort').change`, make use of a Class that you give to all select functions.

You need to make it like this `$('.price_sort').change` and give all your selects this: `class="price_sort"` instead of `id="price_sort"`

Comment: Well, if i do so, how i'm supposed to record values in to a different variables?

Comment: You can still leave the id="" on there and then get the value from the id [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript)